# How to invalidate session when browser tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I am facing one problem in clean up activity. When I logout from my application at that time I am able do the clean activity as well as session.invalidate(). But when I close the browser tab or close the browser then I am unable do clean activity. I already read many things for this but I didn't find any suitable solution for it. I already tried with window.onunload() but it is not working in my case. Because it is generated even I click on back button or any other activity. Is there any solution for it?  If not, then Is there any ground work which is work in chrome,Mozilla and IE as well?

Comment: The session will be invalidated after it times out. What's the specific problem? Cached pages?

Comment: Actually I have to do some clean activity like delete the some rows from table. And Cached pages is also giving problem like I copy the URL and then close the tab . Then I pest that URL on different tab then my page is coming. But main problem that I have to delete some rows before session invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

The sessionDestroyed() method will be called by the servlet container whenever an existing session is invalidated.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener 
{   
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {}
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {       
   HttpSession session = event.getSession();
   //clean up code      
   }   
}

<listener>
    <description>Session Listener</description>
    <listener-class>com.demo.SessionExpiryListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

### CACHE REMOVE

```
response.setHeader("pragma","no-cache");//HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.addDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setDateHeader("max-age", 0);
//response.setIntHeader ("Expires", -1);
//prevents caching at the proxy server
response.addHeader("cache-Control", "private");
```

---

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function disableBackButton()
{
   window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
</script>


< body  onunload="disableBackButton()" onload="disableBackButton()" >
```

Comment: To check disableBackButton() you have to remove all browser cache (manually).